# $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] Dropping first 3 characters of the request string

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, slim

I am running Slim() API and I am coming across a strange error. I am wondering why my PATH_INFO variable is dropping the first 3 letters of my Request

path I am requesting d

> omain.com/cis/report/index

the Path info variable is giving me.

> /ort/index

my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /cis/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

After doing some research into what is going on I found that my server is passing

```
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] = "/xrs/cis/index.php"
```

which is causing the Environment.php to use the

```
dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) === "/xrs/cis/"
```

So what I need to do at this point is in my .htaccess file change it so either

```
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] = "/cis/index.php"
```

or

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = "/xrs/cis/report/index"
```

As of now, the Apache server is set up with dynamic vhosts based on subdomains i.e. xrs.domain.com redirects to /htdocs/xrs/

Comment: how about using $env['PATH_INFO']...? does it work..?

Comment: no that is the variable that is dropping the 3 letters which Slim gets from the $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] variable.

Comment: might this be the issue:: https://github.com/codeguy/Slim/pull/658 ..?

Comment: Create a file called `info.php` with this code `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and then change `index.php` to `inf.php` in your `RewriteRule` and open `http://domain.com/cis/report/index`. Check `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] ` now.